# UIWebView上でYoutubeを再生する際の音声について

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

UIWebView上でYoutubeを再生する際に、イヤホンを使用しない場合でも端末本体から音声が出力されるようにしたいのですが、実現可能なプロパティなどありますでしょうか？

WebViewのmediaPlaybackRequireUserActionはNOにしています。

以下のようにJavascriptで再生する方法も試してみる予定です。
http://qiita.com/babukuma/items/bc6ba19e814d8bb6ca91

その他にシンプルな実装方法でイヤホン使用時、未使用時ともに音声が出力される方法がありましたら教えていただきたく思います。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtubeの再生と本体スピーカー/イヤホンの音の出力先を変更する実装です。

AVAudioSessionのoverrideOutputAudioPortメソッドで値設定することで制御しています。

AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeakerを設定すると本体スピーカーからの出力となります。

リファレンスは以下です。

[AVAudioSession Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/)

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWebView *webView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *loadBtn;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISwitch *portSwitch;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
    [audioSession overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:nil];
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];

    self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.webView];

    self.loadBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    self.loadBtn.frame = CGRectMake(40, 400, 80, 32);
    [self.loadBtn setTitle:@"load" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.loadBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(loadBtn_action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:self.loadBtn];

    self.portSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 400, 120, 32)];
    [self.portSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:self.portSwitch];
}

- (void)loadBtn_action:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NB_gAf4wP-I"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}

- (void)switchValueChanged:(UISwitch *)sender
{
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

    if (sender.on) {
        [audioSession overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:nil];
    }
    else {
        [audioSession overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:nil];
    }
}

@end
```

Xcode6.4で作成。

「Single View Application」で新Projectを作りViewController.mに上記を記述。
アプリ起動後、loadボタンでYoutube動画を読み込み再生してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみます！